# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Tags: r

I keep getting the error mentioned and the only thing I am trying to do is to run a simple `sum()` function. The data here is from the base datasets package, which you can load into your R session in the first line of code `data(UCBAdmissions)`.

```
data(UCBAdmissions)
data <- data.frame(UCBAdmissions)

data %>% 
  filter(Gender == "Female") %>%
  summarise(
    sum(Freq)
  )
```

By doing this, the code works, but I don't understand why without the `summarise()` function doesn't work

The only thing I want to know is the number of Female in the data. If you guys can think of a better solution please let me know

Comment: Please provide sample data in a copy&paste-able format (e.g. using dput) not as an image. Check `Freq` class probably its a character.

Comment: `with(data, sum(Freq[Gender == "Female"]))`. Or `sum(data[data$Gender == "Female", "Freq"])`.

Comment: @A.Suliman Done.

Comment: Are you asking why `data %>% filter(Gender == "Female") %>% sum(Freq)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are five solutions, 4 base R only, and a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)


with(data, sum(Freq[Gender == "Female"]))
#[1] 2662

sum(data[data$Gender == "Female", "Freq"])
#[1] 2662

with(data, tapply(Freq, Gender, sum))
#  Male Female 
#  2162   2662


aggregate(Freq ~ Gender, data, sum)
#  Gender Freq
#1   Male 2162
#2 Female 2662

data %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(Total = sum(Freq))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Gender Total
#  <fct>  <int>
#1 Male    2162
#2 Female  2662
```

Now benchmark the 5 ways.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
    sum1 = with(data, sum(Freq[Gender == "Female"])),
    sum2 = sum(data[data$Gender == "Female", "Freq"]),
    tapply = with(data, tapply(Freq, Gender, sum)),
    agg = aggregate(Freq ~ Gender, data, sum),
    dplyr = data %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(Total = sum(Freq))
)

mb
#Unit: microseconds
#   expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
#   sum1   58.946   72.9495   92.31978   86.7075  102.7015   317.988   100
#   sum2  139.752  171.6000  197.02931  187.4195  213.3305   323.226   100
# tapply  178.584  208.8955  237.48214  237.8795  259.6350   366.596   100
#    agg 2824.940 2959.0000 3194.69868 3070.5720 3343.5465  5156.801   100
#  dplyr 3239.238 3361.0070 4377.61585 3506.0325 3753.1655 82005.883   100
```

The base R solutions are clearly faster.

The `microbenchmark` graph needs `ggplot2`.

```
autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

Comment: @RichScriven True, they only add half the `Freq` values. But `tapply` is also faster. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(Number=n()) 

 # A tibble: 2 x 2
  Gender Number
  <fct>   <int>
1 Male        8
2 Female      8
```

Using Base R

```
nrow(data[data$Gender=='Female',])
```